# Drupal 7: SQLSTATE[23000] ERROR after installing module

Tags: mysql, drupal-7

after installing and activating "filter_harmonizer" I get the following SQL-error:

`PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'bartik-views-standorte-block' for key 'tmd': INSERT INTO {block} (module, delta, theme, status, weight, region, pages, cache) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2, :db_insert_placeholder_3, :db_insert_placeholder_4, :db_insert_placeholder_5, :db_insert_placeholder_6, :db_insert_placeholder_7); Array ( [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => views [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => standorte-block [:db_insert_placeholder_2] => bartik [:db_insert_placeholder_3] => 0 [:db_insert_placeholder_4] => 0 [:db_insert_placeholder_5] => -1 [:db_insert_placeholder_6] => [:db_insert_placeholder_7] => -1 ) in drupal_write_record() (line 7166 of /is/htdocs/xyz/www/meineseite/includes/common.inc).`

Now there is only one node displayed, the others couldn't be found by drupal.

On the admin pages there is the following error shown:

```
no administrationobjects available
```

Can anyoune help me how to solve the problem? I'm not an SQL-crack, so I need a bit more help.

Thanks a lot!